# Camera Intent launch inside an activity

Tags: android, android-camera, android-service

I have an activity called MainActivity and a Service called CameraService which binds to a socket port. Whenever the socket receives the string "camera" the Service broadcast to MainActivity to launch camera.

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity._LAUNCH_CAMERA_ACTION);
sendBroadcast(launchIntent);
```

`MainActivity` registers `_LAUNCH_CAMERA_ACTION` and a BroadcastReceiver.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(_LAUNCH_CAMERA_ACTION);
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if (_LAUNCH_CAMERA_ACTION.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
       }
}
}, filter);
```

Whenever the camera intent is called the program presents an unhandled exception and it terminates because of the exception.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: The exception thrown: The application ... has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Comment: This is not the exception. Use logcat to get the whole log and than check for lines with ERROR in them.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788413/camera-launch-on-button-click-in-android) post you can do:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");  
     startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

And add Camers Uses Permission in your manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```