# An intent to invoke a camera, shot a picture and receive the uri?

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

My application takes pictures from camera by using `Camera API`.

However, I would prefer invoking the `stock Camera application` and receive back the `Uri` of the saved picture.

(I would prefer it that way because the Camera application has many features readily available which I otherwise have to code in my app).

Do you know if there is an intent for invoking the `stock Camera` that way?

Answer (score 0):

To exploit the Default `Camera API` and to get back the saved picture `URI`, you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945517/default-camera-to-take-a-picture-in-android/5945529#5945529).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

and for retrieving the image try :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
          bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture images using camera call this intent

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, requestCode);
```

and to handle the callback use onActivityResult function

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

Bitmap mImageBitmap;
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            mImageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    (Bitmap) extras.get("data"), 100, 100, false);
}
```

mImageBitmap will hold the image that you captured