# How to open default camera without showing chooser?

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

How to open default camera in your application?

I don't want to open chooser for it (its client's requirement). I am using this intent `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE` and calling activity for result.

Everything is fine but apps like ***Line Camera, Paper Camera*** are appearing in chooser with default camera app, i don't want to show chooser for.

Your attentions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599421/launch-default-camera-app-no-return see if this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> list = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
    for (int n=0;n<list.size();n++) {
        if((list.get(n).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", "Installed Applications  : " + list.get(n).loadLabel(packageManager).toString());
            Log.d("TAG", "package name  : " + list.get(n).packageName);
            if(list.get(n).loadLabel(packageManager).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Camera")) {
                defaultCameraPackage = list.get(n).packageName;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I find following solution and its working perfectly.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.setPackage(defaultCameraPackage); 
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
```

you can filter default camera by setting package in above intent. I've tested it by installing two application ***Line Camera*** and ***Paper Camera*** both apps were showing chooser but filtering by package above code open only default camera.

Comment: seems to work like a charm .tested on android oreo ,one plus 3

Answer (score 0):

The only easy you can pick a specific activity is by using explicit intents. And for the built in camera app the package name could be different and device dependent

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find your answer(and code) in the link below:

[How to launch android camera using intents](http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/)

The author states there specifically  that:
"the code above should start the **default** Camera activity on your phone"

Comment: This code doesn't filter 3rd party application, it will open chooser if application like **Line Camera** or **Paper Camera** are installed in your phone