# How can I force to open only device camera for video capture intent?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, camera, video-capture

When I capture video by using the camera intent, user can select all camera applications. But I want to force the user to turn on only the device camera. How can I do that?

My current intent :  `Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);`

```
private void captureVideo() {
    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if (captureIntent.resolveActivity(conversationActivity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        if (captureVideoUri == null) {
            captureVideoUri = Uri.fromFile(CameraHelper.getOutputMediaFile(CameraConfiguration.MEDIA_ACTION_VIDEO));
        }
        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, captureVideoUri);
    }
    startActivityForResult(captureIntent, 1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/19051279/8770539

Comment: Thanks I checked the link but it didn't help much :(

Comment: If you want to use device camera directly, you should not use INTENTs, you have to implement capturing by yourselves . Please refer : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to force the user to turn on only the device camera. How can I do that?

You can open specific app by defining [setClassName (String packageName, 
                String className)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). But I don't think that is a right way because if you are not developing the app that is device specific, You might get into problem.

Reason is - Every device will not have the same camera app, so that, `application_full_class_name` does not lend to that specific app everytime. It may throw `ActivityNoFoundException` as well.