# Camera api implementation within intent service in android

Tags: android

I want to implement Camera API using intent service in Android, which will be able to capture image automatically, but I cannot find any example for this.

please help me,any answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: search for this answer here, there are thousands of examples. And remember the rules to post questions: Show a little research effort.

Comment: Amit da problem ta elaborate koro

Comment: this link might help !

[how to handle camera intent android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490041/how-to-handle-camera-intent-android?rq=1