# Can we take picture from the android emulator?

Tags: android

I want to take a picture from the android emulator through my application when a button is clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you asking about screen shots?

Comment: I want to capture a picture through the emulator, save it and then display its details in the TextView.It's not about the screen shots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question about [how to trigger the picture taking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent) can help you, and this question about [how to access to the taken pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically) too.

Comment: Thanks for helping...but how can i get this Activity for taking the picture. I am new to android so please elaborate a bit coz I am not able to understand.

Comment: Ok, so it is not related to the emulator, but to your app. You would like your app to take a picture and access to that picture. This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent , and this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically - please reword your question to clarify this.

Comment: Ya..u got it very correct! this is exactly what I want to do. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome :) (but well, you didn't do so much research, did you?)