# Android Issue with decodeBitmap with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-emulator, bitmap, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to have my app take a picture and return that picture for use.  However, it is throwing an exception both in the emulator and on a Nexus One.

Here is my code:

```
private File temporaryCameraFile = new File("/sdcard/tmp.bmp");
```

When chose from the menu to take a picture:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(temporaryCameraFile));
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

in onActivityResult()

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    Bitmap cameraPicture = decodeFile(temporaryCameraFile);

    // resize to fit screen and add to queue to be drawn
    if (cameraPicture != null)
        if ((cameraPicture.getWidth() > 0) && (cameraPicture.getHeight() > 0))
            page.SetBackground(ResizeImageToFit(cameraPicture));
}
```

decodeFile()

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //decode with inSampleSize
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap retval = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        return retval;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("decodeFile()", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

In decodeFile(), the first decode properly returns the bounds.  However, when I call it the second time, I get the following error on both the emulator and the Nexus One.  I tried updating the decodeFile to only do the main decode without the inJustDecodeBounds method, but that failed as well.  Also, I have pulled the file off of the device manually and it is a valid bitmap.

```
  09-20 15:30:58.711: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the content resolver to decode the bitmap instead. Refer to the answer at [Android camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent)