# how to listen to the picture captured by camera in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application I just want to listen to the picture captured by user in camera and increase the photo count.I tried listen to

```
<action android:name="android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
<action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
<action android:name="android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
```

above intents .But these intents are not working for galaxy. Is there any other method to listen to the captured images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent)

The clue is to launch the activity with the intent pased as parameter:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

And capture the result of the activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I just want listen to photo taken in default camera by user and increase count.

Comment: In fact, this method launch the default camera. You just need to increase your count inside onActivityResult.

Comment: but its launching new camera but what i want is user take picture using camera in his device. my application should keep track of how many photos captured by the user

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use picture callback

```
                    Camera.PictureCallback picture_callback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                            // WRITE YOUR CODE WHEN PICTURE TAKEN.
                            // "data" IS YOUR TAKEN PICTURE FRAME. 
                        }
                    };
```

set picture_callback to your camera and every time when you take picture control will come in above function.

you can set your picture callback to

```
if you have raw frame
        mCamera.takePicture(null, picture_callback, null);

if you have jpeg frame
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, picture_callback);

hope it will help you..
```

if you want to use default camera then you can use it.

Camera mCamera = Camera.open();

Comment: I don't have any camera object and i want to use default camera in device and increase the count by one every time i take picture.

Comment: user take picture using camera in his device. my application should keep track of how many photos captured by the user

Answer (score 0):

I know, this thread is quite old and unanswered, but I was also searching for the same solution. And found some useful hints [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742143/how-to-create-an-auto-upload-picture-app) and a [post by Vogella here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html).

Just in case anyone needs something similar...