# Android: Use native camera in custom application

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, image

I'm developing on new galaxy camera.
My application have to make a picture using the native camera application.
Is it possibile to start the native camera application and when picture is taken, return to my application?
I can i do this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you search on google? Or tried anything? Check this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html . It's good tutorial

Comment: Try this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent

Comment: Thanks for replay. I tried several tutorial but the problem is the galaxy camera is a real "camera" and have a native button for take picture and a native button for zoom. If I use                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    I can't take picture with that button. Sorry for my bad english :)