# Tell the Camera Intent to save the taken image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, mediastore

I'm doing this:

```
intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
final File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(storage, System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, id);
```

and to handle get that photo, I do this:

```
private String getLastImagePath() {
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
    final Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns,
            null, null, imageOrderBy);
    if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        return fullPath;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

However, I keep on getting messages like this one:

```
07-02 14:46:54.751: E/BitmapFactory(23119): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20130702_144653.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

If I check the Gallery, the photo is not there, so my guess is that the Intent is ignoring the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` value.

Is there anything I can do that does not involve writing my own Camera solution?

Comment: have u put this permission in menifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Is it really needed? I mean, if I use a Share intent with an app with no Internet permission, I can still share it on Twitter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Like this:

**Intent:**

```
             Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
```

**To fetch that result:**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

       switch(requestCode) {
       case 0:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                   cursor.moveToFirst();

                   int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                  //file path of captured image
                   filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); 
                   //file path of captured image
                   File f = new File(filePath);
                   filename= f.getName();

                   Toast.makeText(SiteViewFieldCreate.this, "Your Path:"+filePath, 2000).show();
                   Toast.makeText(SiteViewFieldCreate.this, "Your Filename:"+filename, 2000).show();
                   cursor.close();

                 //Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.
                  // yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);


                  //put bitmapimage in your imageview
                  //yourimgView.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
      }
       break;
     }
    }
```

Add this in your **manifest.xml**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Hope this will give you some solution.

Comment: To receive the result of the image.

Comment: Nvm, didn't see it. `imageReturnedIntent.getData();` returns null anyway.

Comment: follow that code. because it is working for me. Please refer this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/2737770/1835764 might be help you.

Comment: Check in device. Don't check in emulator.

Comment: I'm checking in a Nexus 4.

Comment: can you get the filename and filepath?

Answer (score 1):

Nirmals solution works fine on all devices except on Android 4.x (Apilevel 15).
Seems to be a bug, but `imageReturnedIntent.getData()` always returns null! (testet on emulator AND on device)
The taken photo is not even saved on externaldir, so any attempt to get latest `id` or greatest `date_added` from `ContentResolver` will fail (returns the latest photo from card but not the taken photo)!
Currently I have no solution for this problem...seems to be impossible to get the **path** for a taken picture on Apilevel 15 (while it's still possible to get the drawable and save by your own)...