# Get Image path from camera intent

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

There is option of capture image from camera in my application.But there is problem to get image from camera. When i use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` this it return null data.Please help me 
get image path from camera intent

Error Log:

```
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.pausefablogin/com.pausefablogin.AddPOI}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=111, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.pausefablogin/com.pausefablogin.AddPOI}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=111, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.pausefablogin/com.pausefablogin.AddPOI}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     ... 13 more
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at com.pausefablogin.AddPOI.onActivityResult(AddPOI.java:281)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
07-04 11:22:36.902: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     ... 14 more
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426178/tell-the-camera-intent-to-save-the-taken-image/17426328#17426328.

Answer (score 10):

try this one

```
 Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i , 0);
```

and call this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent resultData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        if (resultData != null) {

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToLast();

                String imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath );
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage );

            }
```

and use the prrmission what you want

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
    <permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and the following worked for me:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
        });
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        final String[] p1 = new String[] {
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN
                };
    Cursor c1 = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null, null, p1[1] + " DESC");
        if ( c1.moveToFirst() ) {
        String uristringpic = "content://media/external/images/media/" +c1.getInt(0);
         Uri uri = Uri.parse(uristringpic);
            try {
              Bitmap bm = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, uri);
```

Hope this helps as I know how frustrating it is.

Answer (score 4):

If you successfully implement the code you will get the image that is captured then manually you can save it for future use.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use following steps:

```
// create a global variable
File destination;
openCameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 destination = new   File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"image.jpg");

                 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(destination));
                 startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PICTURE);

            }
        });


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {


    if(requestCode == CAMERA_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
           {
           try{
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(destination);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 10; //Downsample 10x
            Log.d("PP", " bitmap factory=========="+options);
            Bitmap user_picture_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        userImage.setImageBitmap(user_picture_bmp);
        } catch (Exception e) 
          { e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }
```

please declare permission and feature in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

if u want in more detail then you can use following link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

i hope you will success.

Comment: what i have to add in the CAMERA_PICTURE . can i add any number or something specific

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> you give permission in manifest file.

Comment: this code  is giving exception in
destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"image.jpg");

Comment: destination = new File(getCacheDir(),"image.jpg"); please you replce by this line.

Comment: you give this permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 and execute your program

Comment: ok it seems like i have solved the problem ... with code which i am going to post please check once

Answer (score 2):

You're probably running a Samsung device. I believe this is a bug that occurs in these devices. You have to get the URI otherwise. Do this:

```
/**
  * (This is a variable instance) Contains the path and file name where you want to save the image.
  * Mainly used to start Intent.Action_View with this URI. (GalleryApp)
  */
private Uri uriImage= null;

public void onClickCamera(View v){
    // Cria uma intent para capturar uma imagem e retorna o controle para quem o chamou (NAO PRECISA DECLARAR PERMISSAO NO MANIFESTO PARA ACESSAR A CAMERA POIS O FAZEMOS VIA INTENT).
    // Creates an intent to capture an image and returns control to the caller
    Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    // Cria um arquivo para salvar a imagem.
    // Creates an file to save the image.
    uriImage = ProcessaImagens.getOutputMediaFileUri( ProcessaImagens.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, getActivity().getApplicationContext() );
    // Intent to pass a URI object containing the path and file name where you want to save the image. We'll get through the data parameter of the method onActivityResult().
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriImagem );
    // Starts the intent to image capture and waits the result.
    startActivityForResult( intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );
}
```

The [ProcessaImagens](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4wa6um5nwyi4r0/ProcessaImagens.java) class is a class that I coded and I'm sharing with everyone. Can use this class to facilitate. It has a very good method to compress the image if you want to save images in the database. In its `onActivityResult()` method do this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    // If finished activity on startForActivityResult.
    if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
        if ( requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE ) {
            String imagePath = uriImage.getPath();
            // I will compress the imagem. Read the javadoc from method and you'll see which it returns both bitmap and array bytes.
            List<Object> imageCompact = ProcessaImagens.compactarImagem( uriImagem.getPath() );
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) imageCompact.get( 0 );
            byte[] imageBytes = (byte[]) imageCompact.get( 1 );

        }
    }
    // If canceled activity on startForActivityResult.
    else if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ) {
        if ( requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE ) {
            // User canceled the image capture.
            Log.d( getTag(), "Image capture canceled!" );
        }
    }
    // If an error occurred in the activity on startForActivityResult.
    else {
        // Failed the image capture, alert the user.
        Toast.makeText( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "FAILED! The image capture failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        Log.e( getTag(), "FAILED! The image capture failed!" );
    }
}
```

Note that I used `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` because I'm getting the context from a Fragment and not from Activity. I believe with this method you can have what you want. Just make little changes how form to get context.

Comment: It's preferable you to translate and add the answer here, as soon as link only answers are not acceptable here.

Comment: @Math sorry for my english.

Comment: Don't be sorry. I'm just helping ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Media.DATA, Media.DATE_ADDED, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
         if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
         {
             do {
                 Uri uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
                 String photoPath = uri.toString();
             }while(cursor.moveToNext());


             cursor.close();
         }
```

when while loop doing the last itration it give the image path which in captured last time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have put this tag in your manifest file: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />`

And this might be help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10779050/2514032