# return binary data to the requesting application after capturing image

Tags: android, image, camera, android-camera

How to return binary data or image file to the requesting application from my custom camera? Example, return the image cature from my camera directly to My Tracks Application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462549/get-image-path-from-camera-intent

Comment: Sorry but that is not what i want. That question return the image from the stock camera. I want that my custom camera is the provider of the image to send to the other application. I have already made a custom camera but the problem is, when the My tracks application used my custom camera, it returns blank or no image because the binary data was not pass to the requester.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve. I'd attach the library of the third party application :-)