# Android Studio How to save image in phone's gallery captured from camera in the apps?

Tags: android

[This is my segment code for camera.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfTUS.jpg)

The camera functions well except that it fails to save the image. It just hangs there and doing nothing. Do I have any problem with the coding?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you don't provide any code, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: and when you provide code, please paste it in the question, don't use an image

Answer (score 0):

After calling the camera intent of course there's a function that you can ovveride  the onActivityResult()

this is already answered please refer to this link [Tell the Camera Intent to save the taken image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426178/tell-the-camera-intent-to-save-the-taken-image)