# Camera launching when I click an app

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

I am trying to do an android app where I will use facial recognition for providing security to the other applications present in phone. I am retrieving all applications and showing them in a list. I kept a button(ON/OFF) beside every application mentioned in the list. When I select ON for an app I provide security for that app using facial recognition.

Now, when I am trying to open the corresponding app it should first go to front camera. Here is where I am facing problem. Since I am new to android I don't understand how to redirect to front camera when I open an application.

Please help me if anyone has an idea on how to do it.

Comment: Paste your code as well, what have you tried yet?

Comment: Sounds like you are launching an intent to the camera, which most likely isnt what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to launch camera when I select the button as ON

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2737770/1384010 @venky4t

Comment: So far I have done the interface where I show apps in a screen with button beside it. After that I am struck. Not sure how to post a picture of that here. From that point I am trying to search how to launch camera when I am trying to open application.