# App crashes when I open camera

Tags: java, android, android-studio, camera

When I press button to open the camera, my app crashes.

### LogCat:

```
05-18 19:33:41.644 386-2041/? E/CameraService: Permission Denial: can't use the camera pid=18519, uid=10159
05-18 19:33:41.648 18519-18519/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: involved.pose9, PID: 18519
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:511)
  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:368)
  at involved.pose9.CameraActivity$1.onClick(CameraActivity.java:48)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: seems pretty obvious by the error, you dont have the correct permissions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android camera intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

To call the camera you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivity(intent);
```

The image will be automatically saved in a default directory.

And you need to set the permission for the camera in your **AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"> </uses-permission>
```

Now using above approach Devices with no camera or devices only with front camera won't be able to find/install the app.

Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Using this approach will reduce the amount of devices visible in the playstore. Devices with no camera or devices only with front camera won't be able to find/install the app.

Comment: @euryp Yes this can be problem.