# How To add Focus, Brightness and Zoom controls to react native camera?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I used `react-native-camera` on my iOS app and now trying to add Focus, Brightness and Zoom controls to it. So far I was unable to come up with a solution. Any idea how to do this?

I tried to find an option in different react native camera packages. Also posted in their git repos for help. Finally tried this post: https://medium.com/react-native-development/react-native-camera-app-with-live-preview-saturation-and-brightness-filters-d34535cc6d14 Where they take a photo from the camera every 5 milliseconds and adjust its brightness which seems to be very unstable and it makes the app crash.

Comment: In the spirit of Stackoverflow's guidelines, can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: @gtfargo Just updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the focus and zoom functionalities with `react-native-camera`.

Unluckily [the focus api has many bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55966437/7295772) and the zoom functionalities will not render fast enough with javascript.

Maybe a solution is **not** using `react-native-camera` and instead [just writing an intent to open the default camera application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2729382/7295772)

[The following app](https://synced.to/) uses this solution, all the camera functionalities work perfectly.

Could they re-open the issue as it seems to not be solved? 
Developers may need to review all the open issues to estimate the project deadlines.

[image: example]