# How to implement an image preview before confirming capture?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

Let me start off by saying I know there are many similar questions however they discuss different scenarios slightly different from mine and I'm having a hard time understanding the documentation so I'm having a hard time making them fit my case.

I am simply trying to grant the user a preview screen where he can choose to confirm the image or to capture a new one. The camera component of my app is just a pipeline so I don't want to save the image and that's why I'm not using intents.

I had thought it would be a simple matter to capture the image (in the class responsible for captures) and receive it back to the activity containing the ImageView and then I would do a simple if-else operation.

The issue I'm having is that the actual takePicture method lives in a separate class from the image view and neither it nor onPictureTaken return anything tangible. So I don't know exactly where my image lives relative to my ImageView.

From the documentation, I gather that this isn't the correct way to approach the confirm capture scenario and rather it has something to do with the arguments passed to takePicture.

I'm really not sure how to tackle this any help would be greatly appreciated. The code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/bfialkoff/Projects/tree/master/CaptureImage/app/src/main/java/com/app/betzalel/captureimage) (instead of cluttering up the page).

Comment: You have to implement it yourself, when you get image uri then show it in a Imageview, if user press retake, then again open camera activity.

Comment: How can I get the image URI back from   takePicture method?

Comment: If you have not implemented this yet, then you can go through a example available. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2737770/6891563

Comment: In that example the intent is responsible for returning the uri. How is that applicable to my case?

Comment: In that example the intent is responsible for returning the uri. How is that applicable to my case?