# How to capture image from camera and upload to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I am trying to take a photo with the camera and upload it to Firebase. I'm using a AlertDialog to ask the user if they want to use the camera or select image from gallery. I can take a picture with the camera but when I try to upload the image it says no image found.

Here is my image selection method:

```
    private void imageSelect(Context context) {
    final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Choose Image");

    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);

            } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);

            } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                filePath = data.getData();
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is my upload image method:

```
    private void uploadImage() {
    if (filePath != null) {
        //Code for showing progressDialog while uploading
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/" + name);
        //Adding listeners on upload or failure of image
        ref.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //Image uploaded successfully
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(add_property.this, "Image Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //Error, Image not uploaded
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(add_property.this, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            //Progress Listener for loading
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No image found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help friends.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo When the uploadImage method is called it says no image found. I'm assuming its something to do with the URI not being set properly.

Comment: This means that the `filePath` is null, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes that seems to be the case... I can't understand why filePath is null

Comment: You should try to debug your app to see why that filePath holds the value of null.

Comment: @Anon5678 Which toast message it shows when uploading the image

Comment: @SagarRawal "No image found" is displayed.

Comment: @Anon5678 Try my code in the answer,  it works for me see if it does for you

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which I used for my app and worked fine, try it if it works then congrats

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, container, false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Button chooseImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_button);
        Button uploadImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.done_button);
        uploadImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.upload_image_view);
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        chooseImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> openFileChooser());
        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upload in Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                uploadToFirebase(mImageUri);
            }


        });

        return view;
    }


    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(uploadImageView);

        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = requireActivity().getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadToFirebase(Uri mImageUri) {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference reference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            reference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Saved Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        reference.getDownloadUrl()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                                    Upload upload = new Upload(uri.toString());
                                    String uploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                                    databaseReference.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                                });
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(snapshot -> {
                        double progress = (100.0 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred() / snapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + (int) progress + "%");
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Ocurred" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code but unfortunately I already similar code for getting an image from the gallery and it works to firebase.

Comment: ok I'm very sorry I didn't see that you want to open the camera intent and not the gallery intent but I have found a question similar to you see if the answer works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent

Answer (score 0):

A potential workaround is to upload a byte array into firebase; so when taking a photo by camera, you can get the Bitmap byte array from the intent received in `onActivityResult()` and eventually upload the byte array to the firebase storage using [`ref.putBytes()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#putBytes(byte%5B%5D)) method.

This can be done in several steps like in below:

Here I'm assuming that the `requestCode` for camera in `onActivityResult()` is 1:

```
final int FROM_GALLERY = 0;
final int FROM_CAMERA = 1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        
            case FROM_GALLERY:
            
                // Handle image from the gallery
                filePath = data.getData();
                break;


            case FROM_CAMERA:
            
                // Handle image from the camera

                if (data.getExtras() != null) {
                    Bitmap photoBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    byte[] bitmapBytes = getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap, 100);
                    uploadToFirebase(bitmapBytes);
                    
                }

                break;
        }

    }
}


// convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream);
    // bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, stream); // According to the needed quality
    return stream.toByteArray();
}   



public void uploadToFirebase(bytes[] bytes) {
    StorageReference ref = .... 
    ref.putBytes(bytes)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }

        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            }

        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                        byte[] bitmapBytes = getBytesFromBitmap(photo, 100);
                        profilePicture.setImageBitmap(photo);
    
                        StorageReference ref
                                = storageReference
                                .child(
                                        "images/"
                                                + imagename);
    
                        // adding listeners on upload
                        // or failure of image
                        ref.putBytes(bitmapBytes)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(
                                        new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(
                                                    UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    
                                                // Image uploaded successfully
                                                // Dismiss dialog
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                                "Image Uploaded!!",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                        .show();
                                            }
                                        })
    
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    
                                        // Error, Image not uploaded
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                .show();
                                    }
                                });
    
    
                    }
                } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    
                        try {
                            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
    
                            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            StorageReference ref
                                    = storageReference
                                    .child(
                                            "images/"
                                                    + imagename);
    
                            // adding listeners on upload
                            // or failure of image
                            ref.putFile(selectedImage)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                                            new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(
                                                        UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    
                                                    // Image uploaded successfully
                                                    // Dismiss dialog
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                                    "Your profile picture have been chnaged successfully",
                                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                            .show();
                                                }
                                            })
    
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    
                                            // Error, Image not uploaded
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                        }
                                    });
    
    
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream);
            // bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, stream); // According to the needed quality
            return stream.toByteArray();
        }
private void openCamera() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_GALLERY);
    }
```