How to start a camera intent and save picture taken to a specific location for each item in a listView
I'm new to programming and I don't know how to start camera intent from the adapter and to save image to a specific location for each item in the listview. I would like when I press the button takeImage to start a camera intent and to save the taken image to a specific location for each item in the list view. I defined in the Planet class an attribute
this.pathToSave = pathToSave

in order to be possible to save to a specific location but I don't know how to put all togheter.
public class MyCustomAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> {

    private ArrayList<Planet> planetsArrayList;
    Context context;

    public MyCustomAdaptor(ArrayList<Planet> planetsArrayList,Context context){
        super(context, R.layout.item_list_layout,planetsArrayList);
        this.planetsArrayList = planetsArrayList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    private static class MyViewHolder{
        TextView planetName;
        ImageView planetImg;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        Planet planets = getItem(position);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder;
        final View result;

        if(convertView == null) {
            myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.item_list_layout,
                    parent,
                    false
            );

            myViewHolder.planetName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.planet_name);
            myViewHolder.planetImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
        }else{
            myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }

        myViewHolder.planetName.setText(planets.getPlanetName());
        myViewHolder.planetImg.setImageResource(planets.getPlanetImage());


        return result;
    }

}


Then I have the Planet class:
public class Planet {

    private String planetName;
    private int planetImage;
    private String pathToSave;

    public Planet(String planetName, int planetImage, String pathToSave){
        this.planetName = planetName;
        this.planetImage = planetImage;
        this.pathToSave = pathToSave;
    }

    public String getPlanetName() {
        return planetName;
    }

    public int getPlanetImage() {
        return planetImage;
    }

    public String getPathToSave() {
        return pathToSave;
    }

    public void setPlanetName(String planetName) {
        this.planetName = planetName;
    }

    public void setPlanetImage(int planetImage) {
        this.planetImage = planetImage;
    }

    public void setPathToSave(String pathToSave) {
        this.pathToSave = pathToSave;
    }
}


Then I have the listView:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="110sp"
        android:layout_height="110sp"
        android:layout_margin="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.006"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/planet_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Planet Name"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takeImage"
        android:layout_width="110sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:text="Scan Doc"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.465"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I've tried to everything but doesn't work.

Set a click listener on button takeImage and then launch camera intent and get the result code in activity

Can you give me more details please? I think you described the process for setting up a click listener but you didn't specify how to save to specific path the image taken with the camera through intent inside the on click listner for each item in the listview

You can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2737770/24823442

I solved my question with the answers found here and here:

First, in your Activity you need to use the:

ActivityResultLauncher

And pass it to the adapter:
public class Activity {
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cameraLauncher;
    MyCustomAdaptor adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        setupCameraLauncher();

        // This on onCreate or after retrieve the planetsArrayList data
        adapter = new MyCustomAdaptor (planetsArrayList, context, cameraLauncher);
    }
    
    public void setupCameraLauncher() {
        cameraLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri imageUri = adapterStructures.getCapturedImageUri();
                    String cameraUriString = imageUri.toString(); // Here is your LOCAL IMAGE 
                    
                    Planet planet = new Planet();
                    planet.setPlanetName("The Planet"); // Handle your value
                    planet.setPlanetImage(1); // Handle your value
                    planet.setPathToSave(cameraUriString );
                    planetsArrayList.add(planet);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
        )
    }
   
}

Your adapter:
public class MyCustomAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> {

private ArrayList<Planet> planetsArrayList;
Context context;
private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cameraLauncher;

public MyCustomAdaptor(ArrayList<Planet> planetsArrayList,Context context, ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> cameraLauncher){
    super(context, R.layout.item_list_layout,planetsArrayList);
    this.planetsArrayList = planetsArrayList;
    this.context = context;
    this.cameraLauncher = cameraLauncher;

}

private static class MyViewHolder{
    TextView planetName;
    ImageView planetImg;
    Button takeImage; // Add this

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    Planet planets = getItem(position);

    MyViewHolder myViewHolder;
    final View result;

    if(convertView == null) {
        myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.item_list_layout,
                parent,
                false
        );

        myViewHolder.planetName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.planet_name);
        myViewHolder.planetImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myViewHolder.takeImage = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.takeImage);

        result = convertView;

        convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
    }else{
        myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }

    myViewHolder.planetName.setText(planets.getPlanetName());
    myViewHolder.planetImg.setImageResource(planets.getPlanetImage());
    myViewHolder.takeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openCamera(); // THe method to open the camera
            }
        });

    return result;
    }

private void openCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            // Get the URI where the image will be saved in the gallery
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "My Photo");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From Camera");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

            capturedImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
            
            if (capturedImageUri != null) {
                Log.d("openCamera", "Photo URI saved: " + capturedImageUri);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
                cameraLauncher.launch(takePictureIntent);
            }
        }
    }

}


public Uri getCapturedImageUri() {
    return capturedImageUri;
}

Then the method to create the unique image:
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    Log.d("createImageFile", "Creating image file...");
    currentPhotoPath = "";
    // Create a unique image file name based on timestamp
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    //File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File storageDir = equipmentInfo.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    Log.d("createImageFile", "Storage directory: " + storageDir.getAbsolutePath());

    // Create the image file with a unique name
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save the file path for use with the camera intent
    currentPhotoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();

    Log.d("createImageFile", "Image file created: " + currentPhotoPath);

    return imageFile;
}

